# Botones inhabilitados tras descarga de archivo

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, descarga

Tras realizar la descarga de un excel con los datos del grid todos mis botones de la página pierden la funcionalidad (botón de buscar para refrescar el grid con otros parámetros y descargar un nuevo excel con otros datos, ejemplo fechas).

He probado a obligarle a refrescar la pagina tras la descarga, tanto por servidor como por javascript, y no me hace ni caso (es un rebelde).

Me han comentado que podría ser un bug de devexpress... ¿Alguna idea o alternativa?

***ascx***

```
<asp:Panel ID="DivContactosButtons" runat="server" CssClass="smc-gridButtons">
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnXlsExport" runat="server" Text="Export to XLS" OnClick="btnXlsExport_Click" CssClass="buttonsGrid">
        <ClientSideEvents Click="SMCContactosVisitasAspXGirdViewExportOnClick" />
    </dx:ASPxButton>
</asp:Panel>

<dx:ASPxGridViewExporter ID="gridExporter" runat="server"></dx:ASPxGridViewExporter>
```

***ascx.cs***

```
protected void btnXlsExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        this.gridExporter.WriteXls(stream);
        WriteToResponse(this.ExcelName, true, "xls", stream);
    }
}

protected void WriteToResponse(string fileName, bool saveAsFile, string fileFormat, System.IO.MemoryStream stream)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
            {
                fileName = "exportedGrid";
            }

            if (Page == null || Page.Response == null) return;
            string disposition = saveAsFile ? "attachment" : "inline";
            Page.Response.Clear();
            Page.Response.Buffer = false;
            Page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", string.Format("application/{0}", fileFormat));
            Page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            Page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("{0}; filename={1}.{2}", disposition, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName).Replace("+", "%20"), fileFormat));
            if (stream.Length > 0)
            {
                Page.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
            }
            //Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        }
```

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. En algunas páginas los aspxbutton me dejan de funcionar en devexpress v15.1.6.0

Comment: @YasserConcepción ya no recuerdo bien como lo arregle, pero creo que volvi a darles la función cada vez que la perdia.